# ¿Cómo mandar datos a un modal?

Tags: javascript, html, twig

Usando Symfony 6 y modales para mis formularios, trato de enviar datos al modal para editar datos, pero solo me capta los valores de la primera persona.

**Mi vista:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi tabla:**

```
 {% for r in result %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{r.id}}</td>
                <td>{{r.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{r.apellido}}</td>
                <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">

                      <input type="hidden" id="rid" value="{{r.id}}">
                      <input type="hidden" id="rnombre" value="{{r.nombre}}">
                      <input type="hidden" id="rapellido" value="{{r.apellido}}">

                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"  id="editare" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarusuario" data-whatever="{{r.id}}"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Editar</button>
                      {% include '/usuario/modal_editar.html.twig' %}
                      
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eliminarusuario" data-whatever="{{r.id}}"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Eliminar</button>
                      {% include '/usuario/modal_eliminar.html.twig' %}

                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**Mi javascript:**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('#eliminarusuario').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var id = button.data('whatever');
          $('#usuario_id').val(id);
      });

     $('#editarusuario').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
          var nombre =  document.getElementById("rnombre").value;
          $('#edit_usuario_nombre').val(nombre);//Input del modal editar
      });

    });

</script>
```

**Mi Error: Solo capta los datos de la primera persona no importa la final**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **MI ELIMINAR FUNCIONA, PERO ESTE MENTODO SOLO FUNCIONA PARA UN SOLO DATO Y TRATO DE HACERLO CON VARIOS DATOS.**

Comment: En un bucle no puedes poner ids solo una palabra, porque en la siguiente iteración estarías creando otro elemento con el mismo id, por eso solo te funciona con el primero. Prueba a añadirle al id que le pones, una variable como un contador, para que en cada iteración crees elementos con ids unicos

Comment: Algo asi? id="rid"+"{{cont}}", pero como haria para capturar el id con JS?

Comment: En tu script ya lo estás haciendo

Answer (score 0):

No es lo optimo, pero lo resolvi de la siguiente forma.

**Mi boton:**

```
 <button type="button" id="edito" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editarempleado" data-stuff='["{{r.id}}", "{{r.nombre}}" , "{{r.apellidos}}", "{{r.direccion}}", "{{r.cargo}}","{{r.telefono}}","{{r.celular}}" ,"{{r.fechaingreso|date("Y-m-d")}}", "{{r.salario}}" , "{{r.pcomision}}", "{{r.password}}"]'>
 <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Editar</button>
```

**Mi JS:**

```
  $('#editarempleado').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

      var vars = button.data('stuff');

      $('#edit_empleado_id').val(vars[0]);
      $('#edit_empleado_nombre').val(vars[1]);
      $('#edit_empleado_apellidos').val(vars[2]);
      $('#edit_empleado_direccion').val(vars[3]);
      $('#edit_empleado_cargo').val(vars[4]);
      $('#edit_empleado_telf').val(vars[5]);
      $('#edit_empleado_cel').val(vars[6]);
      $('#edit_empleado_feingreso').val(vars[7]);
      $('#edit_empleado_salario').val(vars[8]);
      $('#edit_empleado_comision').val(vars[9]);
      $('#edit_empleado_password').val(vars[10]);

  });
```